Spark doesn't see the jar file
I'm using docker-compose. In my docker-compose.yml I declared spark and mounted the volume with the jar file:
x-spark-common: &spark-common
  image: bitnami/spark:3.5.2
  volumes:
    - ./postgresql-42.7.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/postgresql-42.7.4.jar
  ...

  spark-master:
    <<: *spark-common
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"

  spark-worker:
    <<: *spark-common
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077

The file appeared:
ls -l /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/po*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1086687 Sep 23 16:14 /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/postgresql-42.7.4.jar

But I see errors in the logs:
ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/postgresql-42.7.4.jar to Spark environment
INFO - java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/postgresql-42.7.4.jar not found

An error appears when creating a spark session:
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/postgresql-42.7.4.jar").getOrCreate()
I expected that Spark would see my file, because it is in the directories and the access rights to it are maximum. I also tried copying it into a Dockerfile using code:
FROM bitnami/spark:3.5.2
USER root
COPY postgresql-42.7.4.jar /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/
RUN chmod 777 /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/postgresql-42.7.4.jar

But the result is similar. What could go wrong?

Spark can be used in "client mode" and "cluster mode". Make sure when you are using the "client mode" the jar be accessable in the container that you run the command, and when you use the "cluster mode" the jar be accessable in the worker containers.

You can also refer here to see some examples for using spark with docker-compose. https://github.com/mohsenasm/spark-on-yarn-cluster
